# In a django project, what all files am I supposed to add in .gitignore?

Tags: django, git, gitignore

I am making a Django website project. I decided to push it to my git repo but I am not sure what files I should add in .gitignore

I guess all the settings.py files are certainly not supposed to be committed to git. What other files should I ignore?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django+gitignore

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](https://djangowaves.com/tips-tricks/gitignore-for-a-django-project/) .gitignore file.
Normally you ignore all cache, migrations or short, .log files. Depends if you want to deploy you may also want to exclude the settings.py

Comment: But settings.py has info like db connection data and django secret key, so I guess I will ignore that too? Also, where to put this gitignore file? In my project root?

Comment: You shouldn't ignore migrations.  The whole point of migrations is to keep the database structure with the code.